# Является ли ошибкой следующее предложение?

Tags: стилистика

Является ли грубейшей ошибкой в русском языке следующее предложение? Если является, то почему?

> Пункт договора дополнить следующей редакцией.

Answer (score 3):

Грубейшая-не грубейшая, но всё-таки грамматическая ошибка, и если это документ, то Вам её исправят. Пункт договора можно дополнить подпунктом  в следующей редакции, пунктом следующего содержания:..., абзацами следующего содержания: ... Или изложить в следующей редакции:... Это общепринятые договорные (деловые)клише.Редакцию как разновидность текста можно заменить, но дополнить ей нельзя. Это смешение 2 понятий.

Comment: В стилистике называется контаминация.

Comment: Почему это ошибка грамматическая?

Comment: Лексическая - когда неправильно понят смысл, вместо одного слова употреблено другое, а это неправильное построение предложения - грамматика (как и неправильное словообразование, ошибка в сочетаемости слов словосочетания)

Comment: Понятно. Хотя бы  в систематике мы не расходимся. )))
Думаю, это именно лексическая ошибка. Поскольку с точки зрения грамматики предложение построено совершенно правильно. Относить к грамматике лексическую сочетаемость - это, имхо, нонсенс.  

Специально посмотрел по интернету, не нашел нигде, чтобы подобную контаминацию (типа "играть значение") относили к **грамматическим** ошибкам.

Comment: О да, конечно, это я не подумавши. Ошибка, конечно, речевая. Поспешишь - людей насмешишь.

Answer (score 1):

Грубейшей не является.
Еще и не то слыхивали.
Если и есть ошибка, то связанная с некоторым косноязычием говорящего.
Скорее всего он смешал два выражения "дополнить новым пунктом (подпунктом) в следующей редакции..." и "изложить в следующей редакции...". В зависимости от ситуации правильным будет использовать одну из этих конструкций.

Answer (score 1):

Тут надо понимать, о чем идет речь. Документ действительно будет чем-то дополнен (пополнен), то есть, скажем, к уже имеющемуся тексту добавят еще один, отредактированный, или же отредактируют то, что есть. Если первое, то, в принципе, можно оставить первоначальную формулировку (может, несколько ее причесав), если второе, то, конечно, надо изменить: "Пункт договора изложить в следующей редакции" или как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

нет не является правда